# How to build a gateway from my Linux OS

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, router

I want to configure my Linux so that it will be used as a network router (gateway). Can anybody give me some hints on this? (links are welcome!)

Comment: use iptables for this.  see http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a simple router, there are really only two steps that need to be done.

#### Enable routing

The first step is to enable routing in the kernel. By default, the kernel drops packets that it doesn't recognize; once you enable routing, it'll forward them. You need to issue either of these two commands when the computer boots:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Many distributions have a file called `/etc/sysctl.conf`, where you can put the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to execute that command when the computer boots. If there's a directory `/etc/sysctl.d`, you can add a file in that directory instead of editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`; call the file `something.conf`.

For IPv6, the corresponding setting is `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding` or `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding`. You can also use `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` or `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding` for IPv4.

#### Set routing tables

The second step is to set routing tables. This can be simple or complicated depending on how much you need to do. For simple uses, configure each of your network interfaces' address and netmask, and add any needed extra route with the `route` command.

#### Going beyond simple routing

If you need to rewrite packets, the basic command is [`iptables`](http://www.netfilter.org/) (`ip6tables` for IPv6). (“Netfilter” is the name of the kernel packet handling facility, and “iptables” if the name of the program that controls it.) This is where to look for filtering, NAT and more.

For complex setups, look at the `ip` command from the [iproute2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) package.

Comment: Hi Gilles! I followed your thoughts. Something like this: eth0 - has the WAN. eth1 has 192.168.30.1 IP. After this, I done: `iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE` and `iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT`. I set my client machine's IP to 192.168.30.10. My client machine is connected to the linux server via eth1. Ok, when I ping 192.168.30.1, it's ok, but I cannot connect to internet. (cannot ping google.com or any other web address). I also wrote my valid DNS in the /etc/resolv.conf. Can you help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: @artaxerxe I can't tell what's wrong from your comment. You should ask a new question. Can you ping `8.8.8.8`? If yes, you have a DNS problem. If not, you have an IP connectivity problem; copy-paste the output of `ifconfig`, `route -n`, `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -t nat -nvL`.

Answer (score 3):

First plug in the IPs of the network for which you want to act as router. Either get multiple network interface cards or configure a virtual interface. 
You need to enable packet forwarding from `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then configure iptables for NAT. Here is a [brief tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-as-router-for-dsl-t1-line-etc.html) for the same.

Comment: Hello Aditya. I followed your link, but I have issues with it. See the comment that I wrote to Gilles